# Android - on notification received event?

Tags: android, events

I want to create an Android service that works as the following:

Each time I get a notification on the notification bar,

the service will read the message. if the message contains a pre-defined word,

blink the LED in red. (for example).

Is there any event for new notification?

Something like:

```
@override 
public void onNotification(Notification n) {
   if(n.getMsg().contains("Some Keyword")) {
      LEDMenager.blink(LEDManager.COLOR_RED);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup your service as an AccessbilityService, this would let you access all notifications.

[Accessibility Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html)

Every time there is a notification you will be able to access it through this callback

```
onAccessibilityEvent
```

Answer (score 1):

On API level 18+ you can use the [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and you'll get a callback when a notification is being posted or removed from the status bar.

On older API levels you can use a hack via [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) like @Aadi Droid mentioned.

Bonus: a [blog post](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/11/notificationlistenerservice-and-kitkat.html) with an example about `NotificationListenerService`.